# Disable the bluetooth on Raspberry Pi 3B in boot config

Tags: bluetooth, osmc

I am currently trying to setup a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B for my parents to use as a media center.  I took an imagine of OSMC that I am using, but I want to disable certain features on boot, including the bluetooth.

I tried the [firmware](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/boot/overlays/README) approach, but it doesn't seem to register. Is there a way to blacklist the bluetooth?

My firmware is up to date as of the time of this post.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Edit `/boot/config.txt` and append this:

```
# Disable internal BT
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
```

Reboot.

Answer (score 2):

To turn off wifi, `rfkill block wifi`; to turn it on, `rfkill unblock wifi`.
For Bluetooth, `rfkill block bluetooth` and `rfkill unblock bluetooth`.

(I have not tried in `OSMC`.)

Comment: That was my initial "go to" solution, but it doesn't work. The one I posted below, however, definitely works with OSMC running on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.

Answer (score 1):

To disable bluetooth you need to blacklist it in `/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf`

```
# Disable bluetooth
blacklist btbcm
blacklist hci_uart
```

Currently, there is no way to blacklist it in the firmware.  You can "disable" it in the firmware, but this has no effect on osmc or openELEC. I haven't tested it on other distributions.